# Custom Windows.Extensions.Logging logger not used in Akka.NET actor logging

Tags: c#, azure, logging, .net-core, akka.net

I have created a custom logger to log actor events in Akka.NET, and set this up in the web.config HOCON section. The reason for the custom logger is so that I can write log events to Azure blob storage along with other logs generated by the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` logger we are using. I have set this up in the Azure web application settings. However, the logger defaults to BusLogging and does not write to AzureWebAppDiagnostics. I can't figure out how to force it to use the custom logger.

My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="akka" type="Akka.Configuration.Hocon.AkkaConfigurationSection, Akka" />
  </configSections>
  <akka>
    <hocon>
      <![CDATA[
            loggers = [ "FooProject.Actors.MicrosoftExtensionsLogger, FooProject.Actors" ]
            loglevel = info
            log-config-on-start = on
            stdout-loglevel = off
            actor {
              debug {
                receive = on      # log any received message
                autoreceive = on  # log automatically received messages, e.g. PoisonPill
                lifecycle = on    # log actor lifecycle changes
                event-stream = on # log subscription changes for Akka.NET event stream
                unhandled = on    # log unhandled messages sent to actors
              }
            }
      ]]>
    </hocon>
  </akka>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="23:00:00" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My logger looks like this:

```
using Akka.Actor;
using Akka.Dispatch;
using Akka.Event;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace FooProject.Actors
{
    public class MicrosoftExtensionsLogger : ReceiveActor, IRequiresMessageQueue<ILoggerMessageQueueSemantics>
    {
        private readonly ILoggingAdapter _log = Context.GetLogger();

        private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

        private void Log(LogEvent logEvent, Action<ILogger, string> logStatement)
        {
            var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger(logEvent.LogClass.FullName);
            logStatement(logger, logEvent.LogSource);
        }

        public MicrosoftExtensionsLogger()
        {
            _loggerFactory = LoggerFactoryManager.LoggerFactoryInstance;
            _loggerFactory
                .AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics()
                .AddConsole()
                .AddDebug();

            Receive<Error>(m => Log(m, (logger, logSource) => logger.LogError(m.Cause, $"{logSource} - {m.Message}")));
            Receive<Warning>(m => Log(m, (logger, logSource) => logger.LogWarning($"{logSource} - {m.Message}")));
            Receive<Info>(m => Log(m, (logger, logSource) => logger.LogInformation($"{logSource} - {m.Message}")));
            Receive<Debug>(m => Log(m, (logger, logSource) => logger.LogDebug($"{logSource} - {m.Message}")));
            Receive<InitializeLogger>(m =>
            {
                var message = "MicrosoftExtensionsLogger started";
                _log.Info(message);
                Sender.Tell(new LoggerInitialized());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have a static logger factory to store the logger as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FooProject.Actors
{ 
    public class LoggerFactoryManager
    {
        public static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactoryInstance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in the entrypoint for the actors system I set up the logging like this:

```
using Akka.Actor;
using Akka.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using FooProject.Actors;
using System;

namespace FooProject.Actors.System
{
    public class ActorSystemEntrypoint : IDisposable
    {
        public const string SystemName = "FooProject";

        private bool _disposed = false;

        public ActorSystem System { get; private set; }

        public ActorDirectory Startup()
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddXmlFile("web.config")
                .Build();

            var container = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddLogging()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            // Set the ILoggerFactory from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to a static property
            // so it can be shared between actors before creating the ActorSystem, which is 
            // when the custom logger actor gets instantiated.
            LoggerFactoryManager.LoggerFactoryInstance = container.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

            // Load custom Akka configuration to override the default logger actor.
            var akkaConfigString = configuration.GetSection("akka").GetValue<string>("hocon");
            var akkaConfig = ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(akkaConfigString);

            System = ActorSystem.Create(SystemName, akkaConfig);

            return new ActorDirectory();
        }

        public void Shutdown()
        {
            System.Terminate();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }

        public void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    this.Shutdown();
                }

                _disposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line `System = ActorSystem.Create(SystemName, akkaConfig);` is supposed to set up logging. However, when I place a breakpoint after this and inspect the `System` variable (of type `Akka.Actor.Internal.ActorSystemImpl`) the logger that is used is `Akka.Event.BusLogging`.

I took a look at the [Akka.NET source for the ActorSystemImpl class](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/dev/src/core/Akka/Actor/Internal/ActorSystemImpl.cs#441) to see if I could see why it did not use my custom logger, and at line 441 I see the logger is set to be BusLogging - it does not seem to take into account the custom logger passed in the config at all.

How can I make sure that my logs are written to Azure Web App Diagnostics?

Comment: I noticed you are using .NET Core, please note that an ASP.NET Core application will not read any configuration from `web.config` (or `app.config`). You should use [a separate file](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/3323) for your hocon configuration, and load it at startup.

Comment: Hi @FedericoDipuma, the `web.config` is added in `ActorSystemEntrypoint` and it is definitely working - when I place a breakpoint on the `System = ActorSystem.Create(SystemName, akkaConfig);` line I can see that the config has been loaded correctly.

Comment: Same issue as your other SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51064455/377476